# How send a config variable to a py.test test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a test suite which needs to run with multiple backends. It isn't a simple parameterized test though since it applies to the whole suite (multiple files/modules). I can control the run via the environment, but I'm wondering if py.test has a clearer way to express this.

That is, I'm looking for something like this:

```
py.test --set-mode ALPHA
```

Then in my test I would read this value:

```
if py.test.mode == 'ALPHA':
```

Answer (score 6):

Using [`pytest_addoption`](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption):

**test_blah.py**

```
def test_something(mode):
    if mode == 'ALPHA':
        assert True
    else:
        assert False
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--set-mode", action="store", default="ALPHA",
                                help="ALPHA or BETA")

@pytest.fixture
def mode(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--set-mode")
```

See [Pass different values to a test function, depending on command line options](http://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html#pass-different-values-to-a-test-function-depending-on-command-line-options).